# Training Exchange spam filter via OS X Mail.app

Tags: macos, exchange, apple-mail, spam-prevention

My company uses Exchange 2007 for our mail server (via 3rd party hosted service), I use OS X Mail.app on my MacBook Pro.

When viewing my junk folder in the webmail interface, there's a "Not Junk" button which will move the email out of the Junk folder. I can mimic the basic functionality in Mail.app by dragging the message from the junk folder to another folder.

But... does this train the server?

Specific questions:

1. Does pressing the "Not Junk" button in the webmail interface (or Outlook) do anything more on the server side? Does Exchange used any sort of statistical spam filtering (e.g. [bayesian filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)) based on this action?
2. If the answer to #1 is yes, does moving the folder out of the junk folder in Mail.app trigger the statistical learning?
3. If the answer to #2 is no, is there a different way to trigger the learning?